# Troubles with passing object to Angular's controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, controller, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to pass model to AngularUI's Bootstrap modal. Here is initial controller:

```
angular.module('maboard').directive('tilesList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'client/tiles/tiles-list/tiles-list.html',
    controllerAs: 'tilesList',
    controller: function ($scope, $reactive, $modal) {
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);

      this.editTile = (tile = {}) => {
        $modal.open({
          animation: true,
          template: '<tile-detail-modal></tile-detail-modal>',
          resolve: {
            tile: () => { return tile }
          }
        });
      };
    }
  }
});
```

and modal's controller and directive:

```
angular.module('maboard').controller('tileDetailModalCtrl', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'tile', function($scope, $modalInstance, tile) {
    console.debug(tile);
  }
]);

angular.module('maboard').directive('tileDetailModal', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'client/tile-detail-modal/tile-detail-modal.html',
    controller: 'tileDetailModalCtrl'
  }
});
```

So I want to pass `tile` object to modal where I can edit it, but I got only that error:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- tileDetailModalCtrl <- tileDetailModalCtrl`

I saw about 20 solutions where authors recommend to write controller like this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps obvious questions, but have you included the script references to the needed .js files and injected `ui.bootstrap` in your app module registration?

Comment: @Lex Yes. Modal window opens normally and this error occurs